# Is calling web service in android as in java

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have a .net web service, I tried to connect it in java, so I converted wsdl file to java classes and start calling them and it was sussceccful, now I want to know if this methos can be use in android. should I use ksoap2 or I can to this in the same way of java?

Answer (score 3):

We've been using ksoap2 in our Android app for over a year now, with good results. It's quite simple to use, well tested and can be used in commercial projects. Their website: [ksoap2-android](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `SOAP library` in java and `Ksoap2` is for android.

Comment: yes but how should I convert wsdl file to match ksoap2, is there any generator?

Comment: Yes.. there is also a separate converter project linked off the ksoap2-android website